# Minikube Start Error: How to fix "Unfortunately, an error has occurred: timed out waiting for the condition" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, minikube

Using Windows subsystem linux - Ubuntu (wsl-2)

minikube version: v1.26.0
docker version: 20.10.17

When type
'minikube start'
'minikube start --force'
'minikube start --driver=docker'

Have error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsvqU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if there is no previous data, can you try with

```
minikube delete --all --purge
```

and minikube start .. after

this is likely with the previous cluster. if there is data that you wish to backup, just copy out the folder and do the same..
if this fails, please do minikube logs and check on docker ps

Comment: I tried and got error again. 
In the logs on docker ps it says

-- Logs begin at Wed 2022-07-13 10:23:42 UTC, end at Wed 2022-07-13 10:44:10 UTC. --
Jul 13 10:43:04 minikube dockerd[710]: time="2022-07-13T10:43:04.204449100Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
Jul 13 10:43:04 minikube dockerd[710]: time="2022-07-13T10:43:04.204512400Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Comment: can you manually pull the docker image? that might be the issue..